# Deep copy and dict update in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to get the deepcopy of a dict and update the result in Python 2.6. The following code works well:

```
>>> a = {1:2}
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b.update({3:4})
>>> b
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

while the following code does not work

```
>>> a={1:2}
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a).update({3:4})
>>> b
>>>
```

Why the second code snippet gives `None`?

Answer (score 3):

`dict.update` is an *inplace* operation like `list.sort`, it does not return a value it modifies the original object it is called on.

If you actually `print b` you would see  `None` as all python functions that do not specify a return value will return None by default. So you are assigning `b` to the result of calling `update` which is actually `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Your update method actually returns `None`. `update()` method output argument is actually an input dict you're providing, which is mutated inside a function.